# java collection generic analogy in python

Tags: java, python, generics, collections, jython

I am working on a java code which is required to be converted to jython. I have used somethings like List and Arraylist> in my java code.

I have tried writing codes that use the dictionary datatype or the list datatype for same functionality while converting the java code to jython.

Please suggest if I am missing anything. I am just 2 days old in jython, so probably I am going in wrong direction.

Any help would be great. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use just a `x = []` or  `x.append(object)`?

Python is dynamically typed so generics don't make any sense, because you can put any type of objects in a list.

Comment: List<Worksheet> and my requirement for similar datatype in jython is to keep same things together in simple words. I have already used x = [] but didn't continue with it for same reason as above.

Comment: when you are using a dynamically typed language you need to take care of the type integraty yourself. When you know what you are doing it is ok to use a untyped list

Answer (score 0):

List is an interface in Java.
Python analogy to ArrayList would be 'list', e.g.: my_list = [].
Python dictionary is analogy to Java HashMap, simply said.